# findContours and RETR_TREE iterate through hierarchy

Tags: c++, opencv

How to iterate through the contours if I only want first (root) level and second level in the hierarchy?

When iterating through `contours` in the first code sample the desired contours are marked in the result image.. So far so good..

But in the second code sample I can't see how to iterate through first and second level via `hierarchy`.. The root contour has id `124` but can't see the logic in how to find it's children..

In the bottom the output from `hierarchy` array is posted

## source image

[image]

## code

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::findContours(boxes, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));

cv::Scalar color    = cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0);
int thickness       = 2;
cv::Mat test;
cv::cvtColor(boxes, test, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

// filter contours
for(int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++){
    cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(contours[idx]);

    if(rect.width >= horizontal && rect.height >= vertical){
        std::cout << idx << std::endl;

        cv::rectangle(test, rect, color, thickness);
    }
}
```

## result image

[image]

## hierarchy iteration

```
if(!hierarchy.empty()){
    for(int idx = 0; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0]){
        cv::Rect rect = cv::boundingRect(contours[idx]);

        if(rect.width >= horizontal && rect.height >= vertical){
            std::cout << idx << std::endl;

            cv::drawContours(mask, contours, idx, cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255));

            cv::rectangle(test, rect, color, thickness);
            std::cout << "x: " << rect.x << " y: " << rect.y << " w: " << rect.width << " h: " << rect.height << std::endl;

            std::cout << "\tnext: " << hierarchy[idx][1] << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\tprev: " << hierarchy[idx][2] << std::endl;
            std::cout << "\tnested: " << hierarchy[idx][3] << std::endl;

            for(int idy = 0; idy >= 0; idy = hierarchy[idy][0]){
                std::cout << "\t\tchild: " << hierarchy[idy] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## output

```
124
x: 0 y: 799 w: 2191 h: 827
        next: 123
        prev: 125
        nested: -1
                child: [1, -1, -1, -1]
                child: [2, 0, -1, -1]
                child: [3, 1, -1, -1]
                child: [4, 2, -1, -1]
                child: [5, 3, -1, -1]
                child: [6, 4, -1, -1]
                child: [7, 5, -1, -1]
                child: [8, 6, -1, -1]
                child: [9, 7, -1, -1]
                child: [10, 8, -1, -1]
                child: [11, 9, -1, -1]
                child: [12, 10, -1, -1]
                child: [13, 11, -1, -1]
                child: [14, 12, -1, -1]
                child: [15, 13, -1, -1]
                child: [16, 14, -1, -1]
                child: [17, 15, -1, -1]
                child: [18, 16, -1, -1]
                child: [19, 17, -1, -1]
                child: [20, 18, -1, -1]
                child: [21, 19, -1, -1]
                child: [22, 20, -1, -1]
                child: [23, 21, -1, -1]
                child: [24, 22, -1, -1]
                child: [25, 23, -1, -1]
                child: [26, 24, -1, -1]
                child: [27, 25, -1, -1]
                child: [28, 26, -1, -1]
                child: [29, 27, -1, -1]
                child: [30, 28, -1, -1]
                child: [31, 29, -1, -1]
                child: [32, 30, -1, -1]
                child: [33, 31, -1, -1]
                child: [34, 32, -1, -1]
                child: [35, 33, -1, -1]
                child: [36, 34, -1, -1]
                child: [37, 35, -1, -1]
                child: [38, 36, -1, -1]
                child: [39, 37, -1, -1]
                child: [40, 38, -1, -1]
                child: [41, 39, -1, -1]
                child: [42, 40, -1, -1]
                child: [43, 41, -1, -1]
                child: [44, 42, -1, -1]
                child: [45, 43, -1, -1]
                child: [46, 44, -1, -1]
                child: [47, 45, -1, -1]
                child: [48, 46, -1, -1]
                child: [49, 47, -1, -1]
                child: [50, 48, -1, -1]
                child: [51, 49, -1, -1]
                child: [52, 50, -1, -1]
                child: [53, 51, -1, -1]
                child: [54, 52, -1, -1]
                child: [55, 53, -1, -1]
                child: [56, 54, -1, -1]
                child: [57, 55, -1, -1]
                child: [58, 56, -1, -1]
                child: [59, 57, -1, -1]
                child: [60, 58, -1, -1]
                child: [61, 59, -1, -1]
                child: [62, 60, -1, -1]
                child: [63, 61, -1, -1]
                child: [64, 62, -1, -1]
                child: [65, 63, -1, -1]
                child: [66, 64, -1, -1]
                child: [67, 65, -1, -1]
                child: [68, 66, -1, -1]
                child: [69, 67, -1, -1]
                child: [70, 68, -1, -1]
                child: [71, 69, -1, -1]
                child: [72, 70, -1, -1]
                child: [73, 71, -1, -1]
                child: [74, 72, -1, -1]
                child: [75, 73, -1, -1]
                child: [76, 74, -1, -1]
                child: [77, 75, -1, -1]
                child: [78, 76, -1, -1]
                child: [79, 77, -1, -1]
                child: [80, 78, -1, -1]
                child: [81, 79, -1, -1]
                child: [82, 80, -1, -1]
                child: [83, 81, -1, -1]
                child: [84, 82, -1, -1]
                child: [85, 83, -1, -1]
                child: [86, 84, -1, -1]
                child: [87, 85, -1, -1]
                child: [88, 86, -1, -1]
                child: [89, 87, -1, -1]
                child: [90, 88, -1, -1]
                child: [91, 89, -1, -1]
                child: [92, 90, -1, -1]
                child: [93, 91, -1, -1]
                child: [94, 92, -1, -1]
                child: [95, 93, -1, -1]
                child: [96, 94, -1, -1]
                child: [97, 95, -1, -1]
                child: [98, 96, -1, -1]
                child: [99, 97, -1, -1]
                child: [100, 98, -1, -1]
                child: [101, 99, -1, -1]
                child: [102, 100, -1, -1]
                child: [103, 101, -1, -1]
                child: [104, 102, -1, -1]
                child: [105, 103, -1, -1]
                child: [106, 104, -1, -1]
                child: [107, 105, -1, -1]
                child: [108, 106, -1, -1]
                child: [109, 107, -1, -1]
                child: [110, 108, -1, -1]
                child: [111, 109, -1, -1]
                child: [112, 110, -1, -1]
                child: [113, 111, -1, -1]
                child: [114, 112, -1, -1]
                child: [115, 113, -1, -1]
                child: [116, 114, -1, -1]
                child: [117, 115, -1, -1]
                child: [118, 116, -1, -1]
                child: [119, 117, -1, -1]
                child: [120, 118, -1, -1]
                child: [121, 119, -1, -1]
                child: [122, 120, -1, -1]
                child: [123, 121, -1, -1]
                child: [124, 122, -1, -1]
                child: [213, 123, 125, -1]
                child: [214, 124, -1, -1]
                child: [215, 213, -1, -1]
                child: [216, 214, -1, -1]
                child: [217, 215, -1, -1]
                child: [218, 216, -1, -1]
                child: [219, 217, -1, -1]
                child: [220, 218, -1, -1]
                child: [221, 219, -1, -1]
                child: [222, 220, -1, -1]
                child: [223, 221, -1, -1]
                child: [224, 222, -1, -1]
                child: [225, 223, -1, -1]
                child: [226, 224, -1, -1]
                child: [227, 225, -1, -1]
                child: [228, 226, -1, -1]
                child: [229, 227, -1, -1]
                child: [230, 228, -1, -1]
                child: [231, 229, -1, -1]
                child: [232, 230, -1, -1]
                child: [233, 231, -1, -1]
                child: [234, 232, -1, -1]
                child: [235, 233, -1, -1]
                child: [236, 234, -1, -1]
                child: [237, 235, -1, -1]
                child: [238, 236, -1, -1]
                child: [239, 237, -1, -1]
                child: [240, 238, -1, -1]
                child: [241, 239, -1, -1]
                child: [242, 240, -1, -1]
                child: [243, 241, -1, -1]
                child: [244, 242, -1, -1]
                child: [245, 243, -1, -1]
                child: [246, 244, -1, -1]
                child: [247, 245, -1, -1]
                child: [248, 246, -1, -1]
                child: [249, 247, -1, -1]
                child: [250, 248, -1, -1]
                child: [251, 249, -1, -1]
                child: [252, 250, -1, -1]
                child: [253, 251, -1, -1]
                child: [254, 252, -1, -1]
                child: [255, 253, -1, -1]
                child: [256, 254, -1, -1]
                child: [257, 255, -1, -1]
                child: [258, 256, -1, -1]
                child: [259, 257, -1, -1]
                child: [260, 258, -1, -1]
                child: [261, 259, -1, -1]
                child: [262, 260, -1, -1]
                child: [263, 261, -1, -1]
                child: [264, 262, -1, -1]
                child: [265, 263, -1, -1]
                child: [266, 264, -1, -1]
                child: [267, 265, -1, -1]
                child: [268, 266, -1, -1]
                child: [269, 267, -1, -1]
                child: [270, 268, -1, -1]
                child: [271, 269, -1, -1]
                child: [272, 270, -1, -1]
                child: [273, 271, -1, -1]
                child: [274, 272, -1, -1]
                child: [275, 273, -1, -1]
                child: [276, 274, -1, -1]
                child: [277, 275, -1, -1]
                child: [278, 276, -1, -1]
                child: [279, 277, -1, -1]
                child: [280, 278, -1, -1]
                child: [281, 279, -1, -1]
                child: [282, 280, -1, -1]
                child: [283, 281, -1, -1]
                child: [-1, 282, -1, -1]
```

Comment: Well, it's a collection of trees, so when traversing, don't descend any further than the second level...

Comment: All contours are in first dimension of the heriarchy.. and each item in the hierarchy is an array with 4 integers like this `[10, 8, -1, -1]`

Comment: First issue is see is that you're maybe misinterpreting the values (0=next,1=previous,2=child,3=parent) - at least when printing them out. | `int idy = 0;` -- no, this should be initialized with the index of the child contour (i.e. `hierarchy[idx][2]`) Right now you always start from the first contour...

Comment: could you please rewrite my snippet of code? :)

Comment: when I look through the `hierarchy` array all values in `[2]` is `-1` so I don't understand how to fetch all children of the contour with id `124` ?

Comment: Yeah, hold on...

Comment: actually.. almost all items in the `hierarchy` array have the value `-1` in both `[2]` and `[3]`

Comment: Yeah, those are all the small blobs of white that are not inside the table. They are not enclosed in anything (no parent), and do not have anything smaller inside either (no children).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for posterity, let's define some symbolic names for the indices of the `Vec4i` that represents the hierarchy data:

- `NEXT_SIBLING = 0`
- `PREV_SIBLING = 1`
- `CHILD_CONTOUR = 2`
- `PARENT_CONTOUR = 3`

Let's also recall that each of the 4 elements represents the index of the contours, and that `-1` is used when there is no such object.

Let `entry` be an `Vec4i` representing a hierarchy entry. Then we can make following observations:

- `entry[PARENT_CONTOUR] == -1` → This contour has no parent -- i.e. it's a top-level contour.
- `entry[CHILD_CONTOUR] == -1` → This contours has no children.
- `entry[NEXT_SIBLING] == -1` → There are no more contours at this level of hierarchy for this particular parent.

At this point the strategy is simple.

Start with the first contour in the list (and verify that the assumption that it's a top-level contour holds). If this contour has a child contour, process that child contour and all its siblings. Repeat for all the siblings of the first contour.

---

#### Sample Code

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#define NEXT_SIBLING 0
#define PREV_SIBLING 1
#define CHILD_CONTOUR 2
#define PARENT_CONTOUR 3

int main()
{
    cv::Mat boxes(cv::imread("WqP29.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE));

    cv::Mat output;
    cv::cvtColor(boxes, output, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
    std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;
    cv::findContours(boxes, contours, hierarchy, cv::RETR_TREE, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cv::Point(0, 0));

    if (hierarchy.empty()) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Iterate over top-level contours
    for (int i(0); i >= 0; i = hierarchy[i][NEXT_SIBLING]) {
        // This must be a top-level contour
        CV_Assert(hierarchy[i][PARENT_CONTOUR] == -1);

        if (hierarchy[i][CHILD_CONTOUR] == -1) {
            // This contour has no children, draw it red for demonstration purposes
            cv::drawContours(output, contours, i, cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), -1);
            continue;
        }

        std::cout << "Contour with children: #" << i
            << " r=" << cv::boundingRect(contours[i])
            << " h=" << hierarchy[i]
            << "\n";

        // This contour has children, draw it blue for demonstration purposes
        cv::drawContours(output, contours, i, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 0), -1);

        // Iterate over all direct children
        for (int j(hierarchy[i][CHILD_CONTOUR]); j >= 0; j = hierarchy[j][NEXT_SIBLING]) {
            std::cout << " * Child contour: #" << j
                << " r=" << cv::boundingRect(contours[j])
                << " h=" << hierarchy[j]
                << "\n";

            cv::drawContours(output, contours, j, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), -1);
        }
    }

    cv::imwrite("WqP29_out.png", output);

    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Console Output

```
Contour with children: #124 r=[2190 x 827 from (1, 799)] h=[213, 123, 125, -1]
 * Child contour: #125 r=[377 x 99 from (1808, 1521)] h=[127, -1, 126, 124]
 * Child contour: #127 r=[377 x 98 from (1808, 1419)] h=[131, 125, 128, 124]
 * Child contour: #131 r=[377 x 98 from (1808, 1317)] h=[133, 127, 132, 124]
 * Child contour: #133 r=[377 x 98 from (1808, 1214)] h=[135, 131, 134, 124]
 * Child contour: #135 r=[607 x 98 from (1197, 1214)] h=[137, 133, 136, 124]
 * Child contour: #137 r=[943 x 98 from (250, 1214)] h=[144, 135, 138, 124]
 * Child contour: #144 r=[243 x 99 from (3, 1214)] h=[146, 137, 145, 124]
 * Child contour: #146 r=[377 x 98 from (1808, 1112)] h=[148, 144, 147, 124]
 * Child contour: #148 r=[607 x 98 from (1197, 1112)] h=[150, 146, 149, 124]
 * Child contour: #150 r=[943 x 98 from (250, 1112)] h=[156, 148, 151, 124]
 * Child contour: #156 r=[243 x 98 from (3, 1112)] h=[158, 150, 157, 124]
 * Child contour: #158 r=[377 x 99 from (1808, 1009)] h=[160, 156, 159, 124]
 * Child contour: #160 r=[607 x 99 from (1197, 1009)] h=[162, 158, 161, 124]
 * Child contour: #162 r=[943 x 99 from (250, 1009)] h=[171, 160, 163, 124]
 * Child contour: #171 r=[243 x 99 from (3, 1009)] h=[173, 162, 172, 124]
 * Child contour: #173 r=[377 x 98 from (1808, 907)] h=[174, 171, -1, 124]
 * Child contour: #174 r=[607 x 98 from (1197, 907)] h=[175, 173, -1, 124]
 * Child contour: #175 r=[943 x 98 from (250, 907)] h=[182, 174, 176, 124]
 * Child contour: #182 r=[243 x 100 from (3, 907)] h=[183, 175, -1, 124]
 * Child contour: #183 r=[377 x 98 from (1808, 805)] h=[187, 182, 184, 124]
 * Child contour: #187 r=[607 x 98 from (1197, 805)] h=[199, 183, 188, 124]
 * Child contour: #199 r=[943 x 98 from (250, 805)] h=[208, 187, 200, 124]
 * Child contour: #208 r=[243 x 98 from (3, 805)] h=[-1, 199, 209, 124]
```

---

#### Output image

Top-level contours without children are filled red. Top-level contours with children are filled blue. Second-level contours are filled green.

[image: Sample output]

Comment: great answer.. now I get the logic with the `hierarchy` :)

Comment: btw. do you know a good way to check if the second level contour is a rectangle? I want to make sure that content inside the cell does not intersect/is a part of cell